# Objective C - Extract substring by finding first and second occurrence of a character

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I am trying to port my Android app to iOS. I need to extract the string present between the first and second occurrence of the single quote `'` character.

For example, from `javascript:popUpWindow7('news_details.asp?slno=2029',620,300,100,100,'yes')`, I need to extract `news_details.asp?slno=2029`.

In Java, I did this:

```
String inputUrl = "javascript:popUpWindow7('news_details.asp?slno=2029',620,300,100,100,'yes')";
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
url.append(inputUrl.substring(inputUrl.indexOf('\'')+1, 
                inputUrl.indexOf('\'',inputUrl.indexOf('\'')+1)));
```

I can't find any method similar to indexOf in Objective C, so I did the following:

```
NSUInteger length =0;
NSMutableString* url;

NSString* urlToDecode = @"javascript:popUpWindow7('news_details.asp?slno=2029',620,300,100,100,'yes')";

for (NSInteger i=[urlToDecode rangeOfString:@"\'"].location +1; i<urlToDecode.length; i++) {

    if([urlToDecode characterAtIndex:i]== '\'')
    {
        length = i;
        break;
    }
}

NSRange range = NSMakeRange([urlToDecode rangeOfString:@"\'"].location +1, length);

[url appendString:[urlToDecode substringWithRange:range]];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Although a proper solution would probably involve an `NSScanner` or regular expressions, and without recommending it, if your strings are guaranteed to have this form a simple split could do the job: `[urlToDecode componentsSeparatedByString:@"'"][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your range's `length` is counted from location zero, not from the range's `location`. A range's `length` is not the index at the end of the range, but the distance between the range's starting location and its end.

How about this as a simpler alternative:

```
NSArray *components = [urlToDecode componentsSeparatedByString:@"'"];
if (components.count > 1)
{
    NSString *substring = components[1];
}
```